# Calling javascript function in a JS file from a JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp

Below is a JSP that handle the uploading of a file. I would like to call upon a js function in a JS file such that if a file is successfully uploaded it will call it. How can I make it happen??

JS:

```
function uploadsuccess(){
         alert("You've successfully uploaded a file!");
}
```

JSP:

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*, javax.servlet.*" %>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.io.output.*" %>

<%
   File file ;
   int maxFileSize = 5000 * 1024;
   int maxMemSize = 5000 * 1024;
   ServletContext context = pageContext.getServletContext();
   String filePath = context.getInitParameter("file-upload");

   // Verify the content type
   String contentType = request.getContentType();
   if ((contentType.indexOf("multipart/form-data") >= 0)) {

      DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
      // maximum size that will be stored in memory
      factory.setSizeThreshold(maxMemSize);
      // Location to save data that is larger than maxMemSize.
      factory.setRepository(new File("c:\\temp"));

      // Create a new file upload handler
      ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
      // maximum file size to be uploaded.
      upload.setSizeMax( maxFileSize );
      try{ 
         // Parse the request to get file items.
         List fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);

         // Process the uploaded file items
         Iterator i = fileItems.iterator();

         out.println("<html>");
         out.println("<head>");
         out.println("<title>JSP File upload</title>");  
         out.println("</head>");
         out.println("<body>");
         while ( i.hasNext () ) 
         {

            FileItem fi = (FileItem)i.next();
            if ( !fi.isFormField () )   
            {
            // Get the uploaded file parameters
            String fieldName = fi.getFieldName();
            String fileName = fi.getName();
            boolean isInMemory = fi.isInMemory();
            long sizeInBytes = fi.getSize();
            // Write the file
            if( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\") >= 0 ){
            file = new File( filePath + 
            fileName.substring( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\"))) ;
            }else{
            file = new File( filePath + 
            fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")+1)) ;
            }
            fi.write( file ) ;
            out.println("Uploaded Filename: " + filePath + 
            fileName + "<br>");
            }
         }
         out.println("</body>");
         out.println("</html>");
      }catch(Exception ex) {
         System.out.println(ex);
      }
   }else{
      out.println("<html>");
      out.println("<head>");
      out.println("<title>Servlet upload</title>");  
      out.println("</head>");
      out.println("<body>");
      out.println("<p>No file uploaded</p>"); 
      out.println("</body>");
      out.println("</html>");
   }
%>
```

Comment: Ajax is the word you are looking for.

Comment: @U.f.O Did you looked at the answers?

Answer (score 0):

Don't consider this as a good practice, but you could do it this way:

```
...
out.println('<script src="path_to_your_script.js"></script>');
out.println('<script>uploadsuccess();</script>');
out.println("</body>");
out.println("</html>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Before

```
out.println("</head>");
```

Put:

```
out.println("<script type='text/javascript' src='javascript_path_file'></script>");
```

And replace

```
out.println("<body>");
```

By this one:

```
out.println("<body onload='uploadsuccess();'>");
```